# Get 404 error when using tastypie filtering

Tags: python, django, rest, tastypie

I'm trying to use tastypie filtering but when I try to get a resource through filtering I receive a 404.

#### code

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
   class Meta:
       queryset = UsersCouchDb.objects.all()
       resource_name = 'users/list'
       fields = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'gender','status','date']
       always_return_data = True
       authorization= Authorization()
       filtering = {
           "firstName": ('exact', 'startswith'),
       }
```

I'm using `urlopen` to access the resource:

```
    info= urllib2.urlopen('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/list/&firstName__exact=David').read()
```

How do I make it so I don't get a 404 when trying to get a resource through filtering with Tastypie?

Comment: Few questions: Does that URL Exist? do you have ?format=json before the &firstname?

Comment: If there were no results, TastyPie would just send back json with zero elements (but would have meta);  so my guess is you've got something not set up correctly.  Did you set register those resources? Did you set up URLs for them?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker, i set correctly urls because i can do 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/list/?format=json' returns a correct list. But when i get with urlopen i don't need to append '?format=json'...

Comment: @GeorgeStocker with format 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/list/?format=json&firstName=David' it works, thanks...

Comment: So your problem is resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no results in a list that you query on, TastyPie would just send back Json with zero elements (something like the following):

```
{
    meta: {
        limit: 20,
        next: null,
        offset: 0,
        previous: null,
        total_count: 0
    },
}
```

So it seems that if you're getting a 404, you don't have something set up correctly.

The following things could resolve your issue:

- Make sure you have `?format=json` appended to your url before the `&`
- Make sure you've registered the APIResource
- Make sure you've set up the appropriate urls.py if anything is different.